# HTMX doesn't seem to trigger event specified by HX-Trigger-After-Swap header

Tags: javascript, htmx, shoelace

I have a [thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/) fragment returned by the server from an [HTMX](https://htmx.org/) request (using HTMX 1.9.0), that also includes a javascript function like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.addEventListener("my-event", function() {
        console.log("open dialog");
        document.querySelector('.my-dialog').show();
    });
</script>
```

The response also includes a [HX-Trigger-After-Swap](https://htmx.org/headers/hx-trigger/) header set to `my-event`. What I want to do is to log "open dialog" to the console and then call `show()` on a [shoelace dialog](https://shoelace.style/components/dialog) that is also defined the in the fragment:

```html
<sl-dialog label="Dialog" class="dialog-overview my-dialog">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <sl-button slot="footer" variant="primary">Close</sl-button>
</sl-dialog>
```

But the dialog is not opened, and nothing is logged to the console, when the html is returned from the server. It's just like the event is never dispatched by htmx. If I instead return this javascript function:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("open dialog");
        document.querySelector('.my-dialog').show();
    }, 200);
</script>
```

then it works.

If I change the header to `HX-Trigger-After-Settle` instead of `HX-Trigger-After-Swap`, then "open dialog" *is* logged to the console, but the shoelace dialog is not opened because:

```js
caught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).show is not a function
    at HTMLBodyElement.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:5:60)
    at ie (htmx.min.js:1:23945)
    at Me (htmx.min.js:1:12341)
    at o (htmx.min.js:1:40194)
```

Questions:

1. Why isn't "open dialog" logged to the console when I use the `HX-Trigger-After-Swap` header, but it works when I use `HX-Trigger-After-Settle`?
2. How can I open the shoelace dialog after htmx has "loaded" the fragment without using `setTimeout`?

Comment: This sounds like HTMX is not aware of changes in the DOM. Check out `htmx.process()` https://htmx.org/api/#process and here https://htmx.org/docs/#3rd-party - This is just a guess. If you found a solution, please add your answers, for others to learn. That would be great.